# I need to get PIDS from a sample MPEG-TS file

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, multimedia

I need to get PIDS from a sample MPEG-TS file,I have tried by reading the  file using `fopen()` and got the data in hex format. Now I am stuck in finding the PID bytes in the whole data. Can anyone help me out?

I have used the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{

FILE *myfile;

FILE *output;

int i=0,j;

unsigned int buffer;

 int o;
 myfile=fopen("screen.ts","rb");
 output = fopen("output2.txt","w");
 do{
     o=fread(&buffer, 2, 1, myfile);
    if(o!=1)
    break;         
    printf("%d: ",i);     
    printf("%x\n",buffer);
    fprintf(output,"%x ",buffer);
    i++;
   }while(1);

   }
```

I got the data from the file, now I need to locate the "PID" bytes in the data.

Comment: You really need to elaborate your question. It's totally unclear what you want.

Comment: @MichaelWalz can you please answer now i have edited the question.

Comment: You need at least show the relevant parts of your code. And elaborate, write more text, explain more.

Comment: @MichaelWalz now please...

Comment: What makes you think that `int` is 2 bytes long on your platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Consider a pointer `p` to the start of a TS packet. Check if the sync-byte `p[0] == 0x47`.

The PID is a 13-bit unsigned integer which you can store in a `uint16_t` and which is equal to `((p[1] & 0x1f) << 8) | p[2]`.

Increment the pointer by the size of a TS packet which is typically 188 bytes.

Repeat.

Comment: that has helped me, i also need the type of PID also ,do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @SaiRaghuramKaligotla Just use the [biTStream](https://www.videolan.org/developers/bitstream.html) lib.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at two things:

1. MPEG-2 TS specification, should be [this one](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101100_101199/101154/01.09.01_60/ts_101154v010901p.pdf). This should give you a hint on how this information is packaged.
2. FFMPEG source code via [github](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg). They have a MPEG TS parser and this should give you a hint on how you could get started.

Comment: i have tried to compile the code of  "MPEG TS parser" from Github, i am getting many errors as "unknown type name", please help me out

Comment: Don't try to compile it, have a look at the source code, especially mpegts.c here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/66cf78e932956eaa7d5a9dab8766efbfc1431e55/libavformat/mpegts.c